# breaking line using sed. sed inconsistent or I made a cardinal error

Tags: xml, bash, sed, format

**EDIT** This ticket is NOT about parsing XML. Please read the question before jumping the horses. Thank you in advance.

A curl call sends me back text (in this example xml) in one line.
For readability purposes I am converting it in shell for my own purposes so it breaks a line at the beginning of each node:

```
cat xml | sed 's/</\n</g'
```

It works pretty well:

```
$ echo "<div><b>test</b><b>an other text</b></div>" | sed 's/</\n</g'

<div>
<b>test
</b>
<b>an other text
</b>
</div>
```

However I would like to break the line after `>` and only in a closing tag.
I have created this `sed` expression that looks like a pretty good deal:

```
$ echo "<div><b>test</b><b>an other text</b></div>" | sed -E 's/<\/(.?)>/<\/\1>\n/g'
<div><b>test</b>
<b>an other text</b>
</div>
```

**however it does not work on this:**

```
$ echo "<file><atime>1559521691000</atime><id>CE0E7BAD4FD4409B2AFBC7895482C296896BF947</id><ctime>1470853372000</ctime><factor>290204195029359</factor></file>" | sed -E 's/<\/(.?)>/<\/\1>\n/g'
<file><atime>1559521691000</atime><id>CE0E7BAD4FD4409B2AFBC7895482C296896BF947</id><ctime>1470853372000</ctime><factor>290204195029359</factor></file>
```

***Any idea why?!***

I don't see any reason why this would be rejected. I don't see any general difference between this and the previous one. I am okay to hear that there is no way for `sed` to do it but I would like to know why it works for that first example and not for the second.

Any good soul that could enlighten me?
I have my own program that does it for me but I want to execute this command on production servers where I can write only scripts.

Comment: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858). I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, e.g.).

Comment: I didn't vote down.

Comment: @Cyrus Thank you. Someone else must have. Well I will take this -1 for other cases when I had stupid questions and did not get downvoted ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search pattern `<\/(.?)>` matches either `</>` or `</X>` where `X` is any character. That is, a closing tag with empty name or single-letter name.

In your first example (where it "works") you are seeing breaks after `</b>` which matches that pattern.

In your second example there is no closing tag with empty or single letter names. You would need to adjust the pattern. Consider for example: `<\/([^>]*)>`

Comment: I was trying .* but it did not work and I read about 'greedy' patter, so I changed to ?
Let me try your version. Thank you Janos for your time.